# Convert ISO-2022-JP format text to Japanese characters using online editors.

Tags: decode, encode

I am looking for Online encoders or decoders which can covert the below text coming in SCTP to Japanese characters.

?ISO-2022-JP?B?GyRCJUYlOSVIJWEhPCVrLWItIxsoQg==?=

Let me know if any java library is available to test as well.

I have tried a few online editors but they donot seem to convert ISO-2022-JP format